# jQuery animation repeating itself upon unhover?

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

http://jsfiddle.net/jDk8j/

```
$(".test").bind("webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd OAnimationEnd animationEnd", function () {
$(this).removeClass("animate");
});

$(".test").hover(function () {
$(this).addClass("animate");
});
```

When you hover over the `.test` element it adds  an `animate` class, which triggers the animation. At the end of the animation the `animate` class is removed by `animationEnd`.

But if you keep the hover on the animation until it finishes, and then unhover once the animation is complete, then another `animate` class is added... triggering the animation again upon unhover. I do not want this.

How to make the jQuery so that when you unhover, it doesn't add another `animate` class to the `.test` element?

Also... FireFox doesn't remove the `animate` class at `animationEnd`, why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you are passing only one callback to hover it will get called on mouseenter and mouseleave.

If you want to animate only mouse over the

```
$(".test").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).addClass("animate");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `mouseenter` event instead of `hover`

```
$(".test").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).addClass("animate");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sYWgU/)

Comment: +1 for the only person with a fiddle demo. Just because it's useful.

Answer (score 1):

You've not given the 2nd function required by the `hover` event.  Try this...

```
$(".test").bind("webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd OAnimationEnd animationEnd", function () {
    $(this).removeClass("animate");
});

$(".test").hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("animate");
}, function() {
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with :

```
$(".test").hover(function(){
 $(this).addClass("animate");
}, function() { //unhover 
 return false; 
});
```

The 2nd `function` is the `unhover` callback

Answer (score 0):

Hover takes two functions, hoverin and hoverout. SO modify it like this...

```
$(".test").hover(function () { // hoverin function
    $(this).addClass("animate");
}, function(){ // hoverout function
    $(this).removeClass("animate");
});
```